# Android Unit test mock firebase

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito

I am starting the unit tests of my viewModel and I need to inject a repository dependency, but when I run the first test that verify if Koin is running the exception is thrown:

org.koin.core.error.InstanceCreationException: Could not create instance for [type:Single,primary_type:'com.ramattec.meussaloes.data.repository.service.ServiceRepository']

```
at org.koin.core.instance.DefinitionInstance.create(DefinitionInstance.kt:61)
at org.koin.core.instance.SingleDefinitionInstance.get(SingleDefinitionInstance.kt:40)
at org.koin.core.definition.BeanDefinition.resolveInstance(BeanDefinition.kt:70)
at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveInstance(Scope.kt:165)
at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.get(Scope.kt:128)
at com.ramattec.meussaloes.ui.services.ServicesViewModelTest$$special$$inlined$inject$1.invoke(KoinTest.kt:51)
at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
at com.ramattec.meussaloes.ui.services.ServicesViewModelTest.getRepository(ServicesViewModelTest.kt)
at com.ramattec.meussaloes.ui.services.ServicesViewModelTest.Verificar se Koin está funcionando corretamente(ServicesViewModelTest.kt:46)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1$1.evaluate(DefaultInternalRunner.java:44)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:74)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:80)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:39)
at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:163)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process null. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@17.1.0:186)
    at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@17.0.0:56)
    at com.ramattec.meussaloes.data.repository.service.ServicesRepositoryImpl.(ServicesRepositoryImpl.kt:19)
    at com.ramattec.meussaloes.ui.services.ServicesViewModelTest$before$1$1$1.invoke(ServicesViewModelTest.kt:38)
    at com.ramattec.meussaloes.ui.services.ServicesViewModelTest$before$1$1$1.invoke(ServicesViewModelTest.kt:27)
    at org.koin.core.instance.DefinitionInstance.create(DefinitionInstance.kt:54)

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class ServicesViewModelTest: KoinTest{

    private val repository: ServiceRepository by inject()
    private val servicesViewModel: ServicesViewModel by inject()

    @Before
    fun before(){
        startKoin {
            modules(
                module {
                    single<ServiceRepository> { ServicesRepositoryImpl()}
                    single { ServicesViewModel(get()) }
                })
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun `Verify if Koin is running`(){
        assertEquals(repository, servicesViewModel.repository)
    }
}
```

I'm open to suggestions

Comment: The problem is the FirebaseApp is not initialized, the firebase plugin use the google-service.json when is used on the app module, but for testing you have to do it yourself look at this example repo https://github.com/cutiko/espressofirebase amd btw you should integratuon testing firebase not mock, you can pass predefined results to the consequences of the firebase request and unit test that, but firebase should be integration

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I don't need to inject the repository, the correctly is:

```
@Mock
private val repository: ServiceRepository
private val servicesViewModel: ServicesViewModel by inject()

@Before
fun before(){
    startKoin {
        modules(
            module {
                single { ServicesViewModel(repository) }
            })
    }
}
```

And now I can write my tests for my ViewModel ! Thanks for the Answer